# Vue глобальная переменная

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Я объявил глобальную переменную во Vue следующим образом:

```
const windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth)
const windowHeight = ref(window.innerHeight)
app.config.globalProperties.$windowWidth = windowWidth
app.config.globalProperties.$windowHeight = windowHeight
```

также добавил обработчики для отлавливания события изменения ширины и высоты страницы:

```
onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
})

onUnmounted(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
})
```

Вот handleResize:

```
const handleResize = () => {
    windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth
    windowHeight.value = window.innerHeight
}
```

И в компоненте в templat'e вывожу значение переменной высоты:

```
<template>
Высота - {{ this.$windowHeight }} px
</template>
```

**Все отлично работает. При изменении высоты - цифра на странице меняется**

Но теперь в том же компоненте пытаюсь сделать так:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

onMounted(() => {
    // Это не работает:
    console.log(this.$windowHeight);
});
</script>
```

И появляется ошибка: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$windowHeight')`

Что я делаю не так? Как мне обратиться к `this.$windowHeight` из `<script setup>` ?

Comment: При `<script setup>` `this` недоступен. Переменную можно просто импортировать через `import { $windowHeight } from 'vue';` и использовать без `this.`.